# Python: Remove duplicates for a specific item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of item, where I want to remove the occurrence of any duplicates for one item, but keep any duplicates for the rest.
I.e. I start with the following list

```
mylist = [4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9]
```

I want to remove any duplicates of `0` but keep the duplicates of `1` and `9`.
My current solution is the following:

```
mylist = [i for i in mylist if i != 0]
mylist.add(0)
```

Is there a nice way of keeping one occurrence of `0` besides the following?

```
for i in mylist:
    if mylist.count(0) > 1:
        mylist.remove(0)
```

The second approach takes more than double the time for this example.

Clarification:

- currently, I don't care about the order of items in the list, as I currently sort it after it has been created and cleaned, but that might change later.
- currently, I only need to remove duplicates for one specific item (that is `0` in my example)

Comment: Does order matter in this list?

Comment: what's wrong with your first solution? `[0] + [i for i in mylist if i != 0]`

Comment: I think you are most likely too concerned about  minor performance differences and should just go with one of your current solutions.

Comment: Also, do you *only* need to remove duplicate zeroes specifically, or do you need a solution for arbitrary other values?

Comment: Re: your update, "but that might change later" - makes a massive difference!

Comment: Note that if you're going to sort the list afterward, you might as well sort the list *first*: this makes all the zeroes contiguous and makes a lot of other optimizations possible.

Comment: I ran some tests. It does not seem to matter performance-wise if I sort the list before or after the cleanup.
My list will be quite short but I will probably have a lot of them. My first solution was still the fastest, followed by slicing

Comment: What @DanielPryden is saying is that a different function might be written which expects a sorted list and is faster than any other solution, especially if the item to be removed is the smallest possible item in the list (which for 0 is likely)

Comment: Why is your second approach in a loop? What if you remove the `for i in mylist:`?

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
[0] + [i for i in mylist if i]
```

looks good enough, except if `0` is not in `mylist`, in which case you're wrongly adding 0.

Besides, adding 2 lists like this isn't very good performance wise. I'd do:

```
newlist = [i for i in mylist if i]
if len(newlist) != len(mylist):  # 0 was removed, add it back
   newlist.append(0)
```

(or using filter `newlist = list(filter(None,mylist))` which could be slightly faster because there are no native python loops)

Appending to a list at the last position is very efficient (`list` object uses pre-allocation and most of the time no memory is copied). The length test trick is `O(1)` and allows to avoid to test `0 in mylist`

Comment: The `if 0 in mylist` check is also O(N) so I don't see how this would be better than the OP's second example which was already stated to be too slow.

Comment: @DanielPryden you're right. Testing length is better. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue and you are happy to use a 3rd party library, use `numpy`.

Python standard library is great for many things. Computations on numeric arrays is not one of them.

```
import numpy as np

mylist = np.array([4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9])

mylist = np.delete(mylist, np.where(mylist == 0)[0][1:])

# array([4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 9])
```

Here the first argument of `np.delete` is the input array. The second argument extracts the indices of all occurrences of 0, then extracts the second instance onwards.

**Performance benchmarking**

Tested on Python 3.6.2 / Numpy 1.13.1. Performance will be system and array specific.

```
%timeit jp(myarr.copy())         # 183 µs
%timeit vui(mylist.copy())       # 393 µs
%timeit original(mylist.copy())  # 1.85 s

import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

myarr = np.array([4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9] * 1000)
mylist = [4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9] * 1000

def jp(myarr):
    return np.delete(myarr, np.where(myarr == 0)[0][1:])

def vui(mylist):
    return [0] + list(filter(None, mylist))

def original(mylist):
    for i in mylist:
        if mylist.count(0) > 1:
            mylist.remove(0)

    return mylist
```

Comment: What are the specifications of the computer, you did the benchmark on?

Comment: @NikhilWagh, added Python + Numpy versions. I have provided code for you to test. Every machine will produce difference results.

Comment: This is a slightly unfair comparison because you assume that the list is already a numpy array. If we're changing the input type then we should do the same for the Counter-based approach. Or else make building the array part of the timeit test.

Comment: @DanielPryden, In your case, there are still assumptions. In *almost all* cases, upstream processes (reading from csv, retrieving from calculation, etc) can be further optimised by moving to `numpy`. The point is, *if performance is the problem*, consider a library which is specifically designed to improve performance. Or move to C.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a better data structure for you to use would be [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (which is in the standard library):

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(mylist)
counts[0] = 1
mylist = list(counts.elements())
```

Comment: It might be better so set `counts[0] = min(1, counts[0])`, otherwise this code would insert a 0 into a list that doesn't have any.

Comment: This is a very neat idea but (1) Almost certainly slower than OP's solutions and (2) Doesn't preserve order.

Comment: if order doesn't matter, that's really nice. Order doesn't _seem_ to matter though.

Comment: @AlexHall: It's basically just a pidgeonhole sort, which is O(N). Why would that be substantially slower than the other approaches?

Comment: @DanielPryden because it will execute much more code in Python space than in built in (probably C) space.

Comment: The real win with this approach is if the OP could just use a `Counter` rather than a `list` throughout the program. Using the right data structure for the job will have a bigger impact on the program than any micro-optimization would.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generator-based approach with approximately O(n) complexity that also preserves the order of the original list:

```
In [62]: def remove_dup(lst, item):
    ...:     temp = [item]
    ...:     for i in lst:
    ...:         if i != item:
    ...:             yield i
    ...:         elif i == item and temp:
    ...:             yield temp.pop()
    ...:             

In [63]: list(remove_dup(mylist, 0))
Out[63]: [4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 9]
```

Also if you are dealing with larger lists you can use following vectorized and optimized approach using Numpy:

```
In [80]: arr = np.array([4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9])

In [81]: mask = arr == 0

In [82]: first_ind = np.where(mask)[0][0]

In [83]: mask[first_ind] = False

In [84]: arr[~mask]
Out[84]: array([4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Why `temp.pop()`? Why not just use a boolean local variable?

Comment: @DanielPryden Because it's only one item and keeps the code neat. Also it doesn't make a noticeable difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing should do

```
a[start:end] # items start through end-1
a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the list
a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
a[:]         # a copy of the whole list
```

Input:

```
mylist = [4,1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9,0,0,9,2,2,]
pos=mylist.index(0)
nl=mylist[:pos+1]+[i  for i in mylist[pos+1:] if i!=0]

print(nl)
```

Output:`[4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 9, 9, 2, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
desired_value = 0
mylist = [i for i in mylist if i!=desired_value] + [desired_value]
```

You can now change your desired value,
you can also make it as a list like this

```
desired_value = [0, 6]
mylist = [i for i in mylist if i not in desired_value] + desired_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `filter`.

```
[0] + list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, mylist))
```

Comment: You should always prefer using a list comprehension rather than `filter` + `lambda`. The list comprehension will be shorter, clearer, and usually substantially faster.

Comment: `filter(None,mylist)` is better

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes of course ! Here it was just for exemple, it's could be '42' ;-)

Comment: `filter(None,x)` is the exact case where you don't need any lambda, or any function. It just keeps the "truthy" values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) counter 
which will return 0, 1, ... each time it is iterated on:

```
from itertools import count

mylist = [4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9]

counter = count()

# next(counter) will be called each time i == 0
# it will return 0 the first time, so only the first time
# will 'not next(counter)' be True
out = [i for i in mylist if i != 0 or not next(counter)]
print(out)

# [4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 9]
```

The order is kept, and it can be easily modified to deduplicate an arbitrary number of values:

```
from itertools import count

mylist = [4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 0, 9]

items_to_dedup = {1, 0}
counter = {item: count() for item in items_to_dedup}

out = [i for i in mylist if i not in items_to_dedup or not next(counter[i])]
print(out)

# [4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 9, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

here's on line for it: where `m` is number to be occured once,and the order is kept

```
[x for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if mylist.index(x)==i or x!=m]
```

**Result**

```
[4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This approach is terribly inefficient. Calling `list.index` with O(n) complexity for all the items plus two condition checking!